# False typescript errors in the browser window

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a line of code written using Typescript. The label argument has a string type this is clearly visible in the screenshot
[image]

At the same time, after compiling the code, an error appears in the browser window that says that label has the type any.

[image]

Please tell me what is the cause and how can I fix this behavior

Comment: If you are sure that the label param will be always a string, specify the type. (label: string)

Comment: The type in the popup looks like some built-in tool in your IDE (VSC probably?) however the error in the browser comes from the typescript compiler. Maybe there is a difference in versions between both of these tools, because it's strange that the "string" value is not infered.

Comment: kind user tell me about the versions of which tools are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the label to be of type string

```
mdValue = filterData.value.map((label: string) => {
 // ...
});
```

Comment: indeed, the error has disappeared. But such inconsistent behavior of the compiler in the browser and ICE remains a mystery to me. Do you have any ideas how to fix it or what kind of material to study on this issue?